# Moving to Docker From SVN

Tags: docker

We are currently using SVN for our application development among 6 to 8 developers. Recently we have requirement for developing a new application using Docker.

I have gone through the docker setup documentation and difference between containers and images and how it works.I am bit confused how to use this for a application where team of 6 to 8 developers working if a more than one developer works on a same file how file merging will happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use Docker for the source control of your code.

You should continue using SVN (i'd switch to GIT but whatever) to develop your application. Add a Dockerfile in the repository that defines how you want to build the environment of your application using your source code or built artifacts.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/

Answer (score 1):

The only part of Docker which can involve VCS is the [Data Volume](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes) that you can define in order to share your source with any container you have define in order to build your app.

That means: you continue developing on your host as usual, using any VCS tool of your choice, but the modifications done to the sources can be share through a VCS working tree which [can be mounted as a Volume Container](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume), making those same sources visible to your containers.